# Как правильно передать в Base класс аргументы в конструктор?

Tags: c#

У меня есть вот такой Base класс

```
public abstract class BaseView : IBaseView
    {
        public enum ViewType
        {
            NOT_DEFINED,
            CHECK_BOX
        }

        private string m_Title = string.Empty;
        private string m_ConfigName = string.Empty;
        private int m_DefaultValue = MCConstants.DEFAULT_VAL;
        private ViewType m_ViewType = ViewType.NOT_DEFINED;

        public BaseView(string title, string configName, int defaultValue, ViewType viewType)
        {
            m_Title = title;
            m_ConfigName = configName;
            m_DefaultValue = defaultValue;
            m_ViewType = viewType;
        }

        public string GetTitle()
        {
            return m_Title;
        }

        public string GetConfigName()
        {
            return m_ConfigName;
        }

        public int GetDefaultVelue()
        {
            return m_DefaultValue;
        }

        public ViewType GetViewType()
        {
            return m_ViewType;
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return m_Title;
        }
    }
```

и от него наследует вот такой класс

```
    public class DynamicCheckBox : BaseView
    {
        public DynamicCheckBox(string title, string configName, int defaultValue, ViewType viewType) : base(title, configName, defaultValue, viewType)
        {

        }

        public bool IsChecked()
        {
            return GetDefaultVelue() == MCConstants.TRUE ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Так вот в классе наследнике `DynamicCheckBox` я не хочу передавать последний параметр `ViewType viewType` так как понятно, что это он сам. И хочу передать его из конструктора `DynamicCheckBox` типо того

```
        public DynamicCheckBox(string title, string configName, int defaultValue) : base(title, configName, defaultValue)
        {
            base(ViewType.CHECK_BOX);
        }
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Я вам советую использовать свойства, ибо подобный подход (с методами для получения переменных) уместен в Java, но не в C#.  То есть `private int m_DefaultValue = MCConstants.DEFAULT_VAL;` будет `public string DefaultValue {get; private set;} = MCConstants.DEFAULT_VAL;`. На сколько я знаю, вы работаете с WPF проектом, а там это ой как понадобиться. Также имея свойство, вы могли бы уже сделать `base.ViewType = ViewType.CHECK_BOX;` (но лучше наверно как показано в ответе).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, но разве свойства не нарушают правило инкапсуляции?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к первому комменту. Если работаете в Visual Studio, то для быстрого создания свойств набираете `prop` далее клавиша `Tab` + `Tab`. Или `propg` для приватных сеттеров.

Comment: В принципе нарушают... Но, многое в WPF без свойств не реализовать, например привязки и MVVM.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Ну допустим выше я вам дал пример свойства, которое только отдает значение, изменить может только текущий класс, ибо его `set` помечен как `private`. Вы можете вовсе сделать `public string SomeProperty { get; }` и вот уже вы получаете свойство, которое только хранит в себе значение и не может быть изменено (считай аналог вашего метода). Так что смотрите сами как оно, нарушает или нет.

Comment: *да, но разве свойства не нарушают правило инкапсуляции?* — так же как и геттеры/сеттеры в Java, это тоже самое, только семантически объединено в одну синтаксическую конструкцию, все возможности такие же самые

Answer (score 1):

```
    public DynamicCheckBox(string title, string configName, int defaultValue) :
      base(title, configName, defaultValue, ViewType.CHECK_BOX)
    {
    }
```